# Apply ReplaceAll to a whole notebook

Tags: expression-manipulation, display, expression-form

I'm an avid tauist (tauday.com) and I don't like the fact that Mathematica displays equations with $\pi$ instead of $\tau=2\pi$. I know that I can "force" it to display $\tau$ by e.g.
`Sum[ArcTan[1/n^2],{n,1,Infinity}] /. [Pi] -> [Tau]/2` (with backslashes) but writing "`/. [Pi] -> [Tau]/2`" (with backslashes) at the end of everything is very annoying.

Is there a command which would have the effect of applying "replace every $\pi$ with $\tau/2$" to a **whole** notebook so that I can write it just once and then never again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html).

```
$Post = (# /. π -> τ/2) &;
```

Comment: You will need a few more things such as `Unprotect[\[Tau]];
N[\[Tau], prec : _ : MachinePrecision] := N[2 Pi, prec];
SetAttributes[\[Tau], {Constant, Protected}];
(*Protect[\[Tau]];*)`

Comment: @BobHanlon What exactly does that accomplish

Comment: Once you have replaced `Pi` by `tau` you need a way to convert it to a numeric value when you are looking for a number. Without this, `Sin[1.1*\[Tau]] // N` won't return a numeric value. There are other things needed to get it to act just like `Pi` behaves.

Comment: @BobHanlon I defined t:=2 Pi and when I write Sin[1.1t]//N, it gives ≈0.5877, which is the correct numeric value. Am I missing something?

Comment: I mistakenly assumed that you wanted `\[Tau]` to appear as the symbol `\[Tau]` and only to convert to a numeric value when expressly requested in the same way `\[Pi]` behaves. If you `SetDelayed` the value of `\[Tau]`, the symbol `\[Tau]` will never appear in the output unless held.

Comment: @BobHanlon Oh ok. But there's one thing that bothers me – when I write ComplexPlot[z,{z,1},PlotLegends->Automatic], it gives a legend in terms of $\pi$ and not $\tau$. Is there a way I can make $\tau$ appear in the legend?

Comment: `$Post = (# /. {\[Pi] -> \[Tau]/2, str_String?(StringContainsQ[#, "\[Pi]"] &) :> ToString[ToExpression[str] /. \[Pi] -> \[Tau]/2, TraditionalForm]}) &;`